# Add custom 500 error page only for production in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to have a custom 500 error page. This can be done simply by creating a view in `errors/500.blade.php`.

This is fine for production mode, but I no longer get the default exception/ debug pages when in debug mode (the one that looks grey and says "Whoops something went wrong").

Therefore, my question is: how can I have a custom 500 error page for production, but the original 500 error page when debug mode is true?

Comment: can you make a screenshot what do you get on error 500 when you are in production mode

Comment: `if(env("APP_ENV") == "production"){ abort(500); }` is a pretty simple approach. `abort($code)` returns the views found in `errors/{code}.blade.php`

Comment: @lewis4u For production mode I just want to use my custom 500 page. Doesn't matter how it looks. But for debug mode, I want to use Laravel's default page which looks grey and has a bunch of error information on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the best way to solve my problem is to add the following function to `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
{
    if ($e->getStatusCode() === 500 && config('app.debug')) {
        // Display Laravel's default error message with appropriate error information
        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }
    return parent::renderHttpException($e); // Continue as normal 
}
```

Better solutions are welcome!

Comment: Better not to use `env()` elsewhere but in `config`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Answer (score 9):

Simply add this code in \App\Exceptinons\Handler.php:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // Render well-known exceptions here

    // Otherwise display internal error message
    if(!env('APP_DEBUG', false)){
        return view('errors.500');
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    // Render well-known exceptions here

    // Otherwise display internal error message
    if(app()->environment() === 'production') {
        return view('errors.500');
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not do the job. The reason being is that no matter if debug was true or not, it will ALWAYS show the custom 500 page. I want it to show Laravel's default error page with the appropriate error information if debug is false.

Comment: Currently i'm using this exact piece of code in my application and it works as expected. When `APP_DEBUG` is set to true in `.env ` i'm seeing the full exception rendering. I'm using Laravel 5.3. Which version are you using?

Comment: works but gives error "Method Illuminate\View\View::header does not exist." in Laravel 7.2

Answer (score 7):

From Laravel 5.5+ this will now occur automatically if you have `APP_DEBUG=false` and have a views/errors/500.blade.php file.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18481

Answer (score 3):

Add the code to the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file inside the `Handler` class:

```
protected function convertExceptionToResponse(Exception $e)
{
    if (config('app.debug')) {
        return parent::convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }

    return response()->view('errors.500', [
        'exception' => $e
    ], 500);
}
```

The `convertExceptionToResponse` method gets right such errors that cause the 500 status.

Answer (score 1):

In the Laravel 7+, you can do the following method

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        if (!env('APP_DEBUG', false)) {
            return response()->view("error500");
        } else {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, `render` method. I think this is clean and simple. Assuming you have custom 500 error page.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) {
      if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->renderHttpException($e), $e);
    } elseif (!config('app.debug')) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    } else {
      // return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->convertExceptionToResponse($e), $e);
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }
}
```

use commented line when you need default *whoops* error page for debugging. use other one for custom 500 error page.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel `8.x` & `9.x`, You Can Use This Following Method:

In The '.env' file in the root folder of the project,
set `APP_DEBUG` to `false`

then create a file named `500.blade.php` inside `~/resources/views/errors`
(create the errors folder if you don't have it already).

This will render the custom page on any 500 Server error response.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9.x the simplest method is to add the following to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
protected function getHttpExceptionView(HttpExceptionInterface $e)
    {
        // In debug mode we do not want to show our custom error views
        if (config('app.debug')) {
            return null;
        }

        return parent::getHttpExceptionView($e);
    }
```