# Whoops, looks like something went wrong. Even when app_debug=true

Tags: php, laravel

On fresh Laravel 5.6 installation (`APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file) everything works fine except this situation:

when using `abort(500, 'test exception');`, it shows **"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."** page.

when using `abort(501, 'test exception');`, it shows exception trace page.

My question is: why I am getting **"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."** when exception code is `500` and `APP_DEBUG=true` in `.env` file?

How to show the normal exception info/trace when the error code is 500 without deleting `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/500.blade.php`.

[image]

Comment: You were right about both being httpexceptions. [Here's an actual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42629137/3585500) with a function that overrides the renderHttpException in Exception\handler.php. (I deleted my answer.)

Comment: To make that linked answer work you have to add `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;` at the top of handler.php.

Comment: Thanks ourmandave, post this as answer so i can accepted it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ourmandave suggested, the solution was to override `renderHttpException` function in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` as follow:

```
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
{
    if (config('app.debug') === true) {
        //this shows Laravel exception page
        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }
    //continue as normal
    return parent::renderHttpException($e);
}
```